# Fix Missing module Drupal 9 warning

Tags: drupal-9

When I do an upgrade from D8 to D9, I get the missing module message like:

```
The following modules are marked as installed in the core.extension configuration, but they are missing:
config_split_manager
scroll_to_top
splashify
theme_change
```

So I try various methods:

- install and use the module_missing_message_fixer
- do an sql request via drush:  sql-query "DELETE FROM key_value WHERE collection='system.schema' AND name='config_split_manager';"
- do a custom module inspired by https://www.drupal.org/node/2487215

Result is:

- for MMF :

> ```
>  [warning] The following module is missing from the file system: scroll_to_top bootstrap.inc:222
>  [warning] The following module is missing from the file system: splashify bootstrap.inc:222
>  [warning] The following module is missing from the file system: theme_change bootstrap.inc:222
> Don't forget to export your config
> Don't forget to export your config
> Don't forget to export your config
>  [warning] A non-numeric value encountered Output.php:145
>  [warning] A non-numeric value encountered Output.php:148
> All missing references have been removed.
> ```

nothing for both of 2 others ways.
In the DB records, references are still there..what can I do more to delete these of the DB ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

1. Use in URL: **https://yoursitename/update.php**

The following modules are marked as installed in the core.extension
configuration, but they are missing:

- xyz module 1
- xyz module 2

2. [image]
3. You will see the missing module using the **bullet point:**

**• xyz module**

4. Add a folder in **modules** and name it with your missing module. In this folder create a file called (xyzmodule.info.yml) and add the next
   text in it and edit it with the missing module name that you have. for example (**name: xyz module**) >>> (**name: Web Profiler**)

Add the next in **xyzmodule.info.yml**.

> ```
> name: xyz module
> type: module
> description: 'Drupal Web Profiler.'
> package: Development
> core_version_requirement: ^8 || ^9
> ```

5. Go for https://yoursitename/update.php/

[image]

6. Now you can **update the database**

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue some time ago when trying to install a few modules on my site, the following cmd did the trick in my case:

```
drush config:delete core.extension module.MYMODULE
```

More on `drush config:delete` checkout:

- https://www.drush.org/latest/commands/config_delete/
- https://drushcommands.com/drush-9x/config/config:delete/